# Handling Exception in a MediaFile app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a media file app that is meant to play sounds stored in
my raw folder. There are about 32 sounds in all. And this is what i'm
doing on the click of each button:

```
Button btnGrowUp = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.GrowUp);
btnGrowUp.setOnClickListener(btnGrowUpListener);

private OnClickListener btnGrowUpListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Grow Up audio file is being played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainScreen.this, R.raw.growup);
        mp.start();
    }
};
```

I get a runtime exception saying "app stops unexpectedly" with the
follow messages in my logcat window:

```
12-19 12:33:05.420: WARN/dalvikvm(699): threadid=3: thread exiting
with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
12-19 12:33:05.441: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699): Uncaught handler:
thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):
java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.myapps.media.MainScreen$8.onClick(MainScreen.java:244)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow
$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent
(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow
$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:782)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
12-19 12:33:05.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(699):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 12:33:05.520: INFO/Process(563): Sending signal. PID: 699 SIG: 3
12-19 12:33:05.520: INFO/dalvikvm(699): threadid=7: reacting to signal
3
12-19 12:33:05.601: INFO/dalvikvm(699): Wrote stack trace to '/data/
anr/traces.txt'
12-19 12:33:05.982: INFO/ARMAssembler(563): generated
scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 27 ipp] (41 ins) at
[0x27c718:0x27c7bc] in 982527 ns
12-19 12:33:06.011: INFO/ARMAssembler(563): generated
scanline__00000077:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 64 ipp] (84 ins) at
[0x27c7c0:0x27c910] in 1804978 ns
```

How to resolve this issue? Thank you

Maqsood

Comment: because theres no line numbers in your code listing, it would be really helpful if you'd let us know which line fails! ( or use pasty, i guess the context matters )

Comment: The anonymous listener that's being defined (`btnGrowUpListener`) is encapsulated inside a class called `MainScreen`, so to provide the Android `Context` required, the `MainScreen.this` notation is used.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for the [`MediaPlayer` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) you're using says that it will return `null` if creation of the player fails.

You're not checking whether creation was successful before calling the `start` method, so based on the stack trace above, that's the most likely cause of the exception you're seeing.